# How to make a progress bar in AJAX using JQUERY (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Is there a way I can make a progress bar for ajax using jquery using post data (QUERIES) and not uploading a file?

Because the ProgressEvent.lengthComputable read-only property is a Boolean flag indicating if the resource concerned by the ProgressEvent has a length that can be calculated.

If not, the ProgressEvent.total property has no significant value. So my problem is I use ajax for long process queries and not for uploading file. Thanks.

Comment: why you don't use loading when respond success hide the jpg loading

Comment: I already used the **blockUI** library, but if the query is too long, sometimes mozilla kill long running scripts. so I come up with this solution so the mozilla will not kill my page because there is a progress.

Answer (score 0):

Hi from what i understand, you have a long process running on server that you call using XHR, now you want to show a progress bar in the browser.

**Short answer**

Not possible in ajax

**Long answer**

Ajax is just same as http request and there is no way to know the status of the request on server . Only the final output and http status code is available.

**Solution**

What you want is web sockets and not ajax. WS are bi directional communication standards. On server you can keep publishing the status of the request into the web socket. On client side read from web socket and display the changes.

So overall you need a WS server. Send request from client using websocket and finally keep reading websocket for status till you get the results.

**Is this complication needed**

Although this is very long and tedious job i know that some projects need it if they have long tasks. Another alternative that you can have is push the task into `celery` and use XHR poling to get the status of the job.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @xandercage :) I will read about websockets. Thanks :)

Comment: @EmmanuelVilladelreyPalinsad mark the answer if this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

In an AJAX request you do not know the response duration on the time you execute the call.

A solution might be to set a **timeout** limit for the ajax call and animate a progress bar depending on this time. Of course the response will be available before this time limit (at least that's what we want). In this case, force the progress bar to complete it's animation and proceed with your data manipulation.

**EXAMPLE**

**HTML**

```
<!-- LOADER -->
<div id="loader"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
/**
*  Execute ajax request and initialize loader animation
*  @param time {number}  The ajax timeout limit and progress bar animation duration
*/
function executeAjax(time) {

     // Start progress bar initialization
     $('#loader').animate({ 'width', '100%' }, time);

     // Execute ajax call
     $.ajax({
       url: '...',
       method: 'POST',
       data: { ... },
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           // Stop previous animation and start a new one with 0.5 sec duration
           $('#loader').stop().animate({ 'width', '100%' }, 500)
                       .queue(function() {
                          // Handle the response data here
                          $(this).dequeue();
                       });
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, errorType) {
          alert('Error: ' + errorType);
       },
       timeout: time
     });
}

// Call the function passing a timeout of 10 seconds
executeAjax(10000);
```

Comment: Thanks @kapantzak I will try this solution. Thanks :)